# Create a global variable if argument provided

Tags: php, global-variables, preg-match

How do I create a global variable the way [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) does for the `$matches` parameter?

In the following code, `preg_match` creates global `$Hel_matches` and `$Wor_matches` variables even though they're not defined.

```
$string = "Hello, World!";

$pattern1 = '/Hel/';
$pattern2 = '/Wor/';

preg_match($pattern1, $string, $Hel_matches);
preg_match($pattern2, $string, $Wor_matches);

print_r($Hel_matches);
print_r($Wor_matches);
```

I want to be able to do the same thing.

For example, `odd_numbers()` returns an array filled with the odd numbers between `0` and `$max`.

```
function odd_numbers($max) {
    $numbers = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        if ($i % 2 == 1) {
            $numbers[] = $i;
        }
    }
    return $numbers;
}

$odd_numbers = odd_numbers(10);
print_r($odd_numbers);
```

If I want to do some extra calculation in the `odd_numbers()` and also return that (for debug purposes, for example), well, I can't. I can only return one thing. So, instead, I pass a second argument (variable) to the `odd_numbers()` and the function returns/assigns the return value to that variable.

```
// $odd_numbers = odd_numbers(10, $evens); // fill $evens (if provided) with even numbers for debug purposes
print_r($odd_numbers);
// print_r($evens); // debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) by prefixing the variable with `&`:

```
function odd_numbers($max, &$evens = array()) {
    // blah
    $numbers = array(1, 3, 5);

    if (func_num_args() == 2) {
        $evens = array(2, 4, 6);
    }

    return $numbers;
}

$odd_numbers = odd_numbers(10, $evens);
var_dump($evens);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 6
```

Comment: How do I check if `$evens` is provided or not? `odd_numbers` might be called with or without `$evens`.

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php - i'll update the answer with an example